# Moving a PostGIS Installation

Tags: postgis

I have a PostGIS installation running on an old computer that I'd like to move.  I spent a bunch of time playing with pg_dump and pg_dumpall without success.  It seems the normal dump procedures don't work with PostGIS because file paths get hard coded in the output from pg_dump.  Any suggestions on how to move PostGIS installation to a new installation of PostgreSQL?

Comment: I fail to see how "Using a schema other than public" is related to this question.

Answer (score 10):

I'd suggest moving all your data tables into a schema, then dumping just that schema. then you can easily restore not only on a different computer, but into different versions of PostGIS and PostgreSQL.

Storing your data in a schema other than "public" is a Best Practice.

Comment: More info here http://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2010/09/postgis-back-up-restore.html

Answer (score 9):

This post http://traviscline.com/blog/2010/04/28/moving-postgis-databases-between-machines/ seems to indicate that `pg_dump -Fc` is what you want.