# Using schema other than public with PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, postgresql-10, postgis-2.4

I've read (too late) that it's best to use another schema to store data tables in than the public schema when using PostGIS.

e.g. here:
[Using a schema other than public in PostGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43187/using-a-schema-other-than-public-in-postgis)

Considering this is all quite old (e.g. the above accepted answer is from 2012), I'm wondering if this is still as valid as it was back then for current versions of PostgreSQL and PostGIS ?