# Cross-schema function call with PostGIS dependencies

Tags: postgis, postgresql, function, schema-architecture

I have an issue where I am unable to make a cross-schema function call because of that function's use of PostGIS. I have both PostGIS and my function in the public schema, but I'm trying to call the function from my ORM which, by necessity, is pointed at another schema. I am able to reference the function by using `SELECT * FROM public.functionName`, but the function execution fails when it reaches PostGIS-relevant functions like ST_MakeLine. What is the best solution in this case, move PostGIS and my function out of public? Edit the function itself to call `public.PostGISFunction`?  Something else entirely?

Comment: You probably need to make sure your search_path includes all the schemas you need to reference

Comment: related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/292840/postgis-functions/292842#292842

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the search path. As suggested by @JohnPowell, you would need to make sure the user has `public` in its search path.

Alternatively, you could use add a [configuration](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-createfunction.html) at the function level to add `public` to the search path of the **function**:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.mysuperfunction() RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$BEGIN

  RETURN 1;
END;$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
    -- Set path as Postgis needs public but user doesn't have access
    SET search_path = public;
```