# Use PostGIS functions from an other schema (than public)

Tags: postgis, postgresql, extensions, schema

## Context

I have to set up a [postgresql](https://www.postgresql.org) database with several schemas.

To separate things, I decided to install [postgis](https://postgis.net/) elsewhere than the `public` schema, based on https://postgis.net/2017/11/07/tip-move-postgis-schema/ and [Using schema other than public in PostGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43187/using-schema-other-than-public-in-postgis) for example.

I also installed other extensions, such as [`pgrouting`](https://pgrouting.org/) or [`fuzzystrmatch`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/fuzzystrmatch.html) or [`citext`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/citext.html) for example, which by default went into the main of my project schemas called `main`. And also `postgis_topology` which is set up into its own schema called "`topology`", if I'm not wrong.

For my own culture ; is it a good practice to centralise all extensions in one unique schema?

## Error

Now, I want to use [postgis](https://postgis.net/) functions in all my project schemas, but unfortunately, the postgis functions don't seem to be available as I went into this error while creating a database:

```
psql:create_db.sql:104: ERROR:  type "geometry" does not exist
```

What's really strange for me is that, OK, the script stops on this error, but when I manually create the table that precisely raises this error, for example with pgAdmin, it goes well!

## Question

So why, during the execution of the script, it somehow doesn't find postgis when creating a table with a geometry column, but when creating the table in pgAdmin it does?

It sounds like an async process that is not finished...

## Information

"PostgreSQL 10.12 (Ubuntu 10.12-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0, 64-bit"

"2.4 USE_GEOS=1 USE_PROJ=1 USE_STATS=1"

Comment: Are you using the same user in pgAdmin and to load your script? That sounds a lot like the postgis schema is not in the user search path

Comment: _is it a good practice to centralise all extensions in one unique schema?_ Yes! (not so much for the centralisation than for being in a different place than the data) And this schema is commonly named `public`.

Comment: I have this line before all the table creation statements; `ALTER DATABASE my_database SET search_path="$user", public, postgis, topology;` because, effectively, all schemas (included the `postgis` schema) are own by another role than `postgres`.

Comment: doing this will set the default search path for the next session, not the current one. Try with `SET search_path TO "$user", public, postgis, topology;` to set it immediatly

Comment: Great! This works!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The PostGIS extension must be in the user `search_path`. Setting the `search_path` using `ALTER DATABASE` or `ALTER ROLE` will have effect at the next session only. To use the new path immediately, one would rather use `SET search_path TO "$user", public, postgis, topology;`